# Django SUM from INNER JOIN

Tags: django, sum, inner-join

I have a DB like this:

```
class MyCPU(models.Model):
    cpu_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cpu_count = models.IntegerField()


class MyMachine(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cpu = models.ForeignKey(CPU, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I achieve the result of following raw SQL command in Django ?

```
select sum(cpu_count) as sum_cpu from my_machine inner join my_cpu on my_machine.cpu_id=my_cpu.id
```

I basically want to sum how many CPU in all of machines.

I have tried this solution but it did not work

```
Machine.objects.annotate(total_cpu=Sum('cpu__cpu_count'))
```

Comment: did not work means? any error?

Comment: I expected an integer , purpose is to sum how many CPU in all of machines. But it return a query set

Comment: then do `queryset.values()`. Then you will get result as dict.

Comment: What's the point of the JOIN though? If you want a single value, why not `MyCPU.objects.aggregate(total_cpu=Sum('cpu_count'))`?

Comment: I mean how many CPU in all of machines. We need to select form both Machine and CPU table

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using foreign key, You can do

```
MyMachine.objects.values('hostname', 'ip', 'cpu__cpu_count')
```

This will get each Machine how many cpu`s.

If you need total number of cpu`s

```
MyCPU.objects.aggregate(total_cpu=Sum('cpu_count'))['total_cpu']
```

If there are unconnected CPU objects, you can do following to get sum from all machines,

```
MyMachine.objects.aggregate(total_cpu=Sum('cpu__cpu_count'))['total_cpu']
```

I think the last one is you are searching for since there is chance of same CPU object in different machines.

Comment: And then how we SUM them ? Not by write a for loop

Comment: Update the answer to get total number of cpu`s

Comment: Yes exactly. The last one should nearly correct. However it return a little different result with raw SQL. Could you guide me what exactly happened